# Excel VBA for copy selected columns and insert n number of times

Tags: insert, copy, multiple-columns, repeat

I need to copy a number of selected columns and **insert** it to the right side as many times as the count of columns that are selected for copying, keeping 'n' number of empty columns between each copy. Can anyone please help!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I've made... it does the work but sometimes it overwrite other data present on the right side. Any ideas how to make it perfect.

```
Sub CopyPasteColumns()  'CopyPasteColumns multiple times (as many times as the columns are selected)
Dim iLoop As Integer, colCount As Integer, actRange As Range, opRange As Range
colCount = Selection.Columns.Count  'Total number of columns selected
Set opRange = Selection 'The source range that is to be copied
For I = 1 To colCount - 2   'one master range is already present and leaving the 1st common column (considering it is a pivot table I'm copying)
    If I = 1 Then           'for 1st time copy separate code for offset
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, colCount + 2).EntireColumn.Select  'offsetting from active cell
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight   'inserting the copied data to right and pushing columns to right side for preventing overwriting
        Set actRange = ActiveCell.Offset(0, colCount + 2)   'store the presently active cell address+offset for next paste location
    Else
        opRange.Select      'separate code for pasting to saved offseted active cell location
        Selection.Copy
        actRange.EntireColumn.Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Set actRange = ActiveCell.Offset(0, colCount + 2)   'store the presently active cell address + offset + 2 buffer columns for next paste location
    End If
    DoEvents
Next
```

End Sub